# Error when installing fontconfig-2.11.1 on linux

Tags: linux, fontconfig

I tried to install the fontconfig-2.11.1 on red hat according to [this material](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/fontconfig.html) , but have following errors while make install:

```
/usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts: failed to write cache
/usr/share/fonts/bitstream-vera: caching, new cache contents: 10 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/bitstream-vera: failed to write cache
/usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1: skipping, no such directory
/usr/share/X11/fonts/OTF: skipping, no such directory
Re-scanning /usr/share/fonts: /usr/share/fonts: error scanning
/var/cache/fontconfig: not cleaning unwritable cache directory
/home/dn48866/fontconfig-2.11.1/fc-cache/.libs/lt-fc-cache: failed
ia64make[2]: *** [install-data-local] Error 3
ia64make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dn48866/fontconfig-2.11.1'
ia64make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
ia64make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dn48866/fontconfig-2.11.1'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Any help is very very very appreciated!

Comment: This question is off-topic here, but it *looks* like you forgot to become root before running `make install`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Ok,Thanks. But I cann't get the root permission, is there alternative way to make it?